# Fitting a single gaussian to 'noisy' data yields a poor fit in some cases

Tags: python, numpy, scipy, curve-fitting

I have some noisy data that can contain 0 and n gaussian shapes, I am trying to implement an algorithm that takes the highest data points and fits a gaussian to that as per the following 'scheme':

## New attempt, steps:

1. fit a spline through all data points
2. get first derivative of spline function
3. get both data points (left/right) where f'(x) = around 0 the data point with max intensity
4. fit a gaussian through the data points returned from 3

   4a. Plot the gaussian (stopping at baseline) in the pdf
5. Calculate area under gaussian curve
6. Calculate area under raw data points
7. Calculate percentage of total area explained by gaussian area

I have implemented this concept using the following code (minimal working example):

```
#! /usr/bin/env python
from scipy.interpolate import InterpolatedUnivariateSpline
from scipy.optimize import curve_fit
from scipy.signal import argrelextrema
import numpy as np
import matplotlib
import matplotlib.pyplot as plt

data = [(9.60380153195,187214),(9.62028167623,181023),(9.63676350256,174588),(9.65324602212,169389),(9.66972824591,166921),(9.68621215187,167597),(9.70269675106,170838),(9.71918105436,175816),(9.73566703995,181552),(9.75215371878,186978),(9.76864010158,191718),(9.78512816681,194473),(9.80161692526,194169),(9.81810538757,191203),(9.83459553243,186603),(9.85108637051,180273),(9.86757691233,171996),(9.88406913682,163653),(9.90056205454,156032),(9.91705467586,149928),(9.93354897998,145410),(9.95004397733,141818),(9.96653867816,139042),(9.98303506191,137546),(9.99953213889,138724)]
data2 = [(9.60476933166,163571),(9.62125990879,156662),(9.63775225872,150535),(9.65424539203,146960),(9.67073831905,146794),(9.68723301904,149326),(9.70372850238,152616),(9.72022377931,155420),(9.73672082933,156151),(9.75321866271,154633),(9.76971628954,151549),(9.78621568961,148298),(9.80271587303,146333),(9.81921584976,146734),(9.83571759987,150351),(9.85222013334,156612),(9.86872245996,164192),(9.88522656011,171199),(9.90173144362,175697),(9.91823612015,176867),(9.93474257034,175029),(9.95124980389,171762),(9.96775683032,168449),(9.98426563055,165026)]

def gaussFunction(x, *p):
    """ TODO
    """
    A, mu, sigma = p
    return A*np.exp(-(x-mu)**2/(2.*sigma**2))

def quantify(data):
    """ TODO
    """
    backGround = 105000  # Normally this is dynamically determined but this value is fine for testing on the provided data
    time,intensity = zip(*data)
    x_data = np.array(time)
    y_data = np.array(intensity)
    newX = np.linspace(x_data[0], x_data[-1], 2500*(x_data[-1]-x_data[0]))
    f = InterpolatedUnivariateSpline(x_data, y_data)
    fPrime = f.derivative()
    newY = f(newX)
    newPrimeY = fPrime(newX)
    maxm = argrelextrema(newPrimeY, np.greater)
    minm = argrelextrema(newPrimeY, np.less)
    breaks = maxm[0].tolist() + minm[0].tolist()
    maxPoint = 0
    for index,j in enumerate(breaks):
        try:
            if max(newY[breaks[index]:breaks[index+1]]) > maxPoint:
                maxPoint = max(newY[breaks[index]:breaks[index+1]])
                xData = newX[breaks[index]:breaks[index+1]]
                yData = [x - backGround for x in newY[breaks[index]:breaks[index+1]]]
        except:
            pass
    # Gaussian fit on main points
    newGaussX = np.linspace(x_data[0], x_data[-1], 2500*(x_data[-1]-x_data[0]))
    p0 = [np.max(yData), xData[np.argmax(yData)],0.1]
    try:
        coeff, var_matrix = curve_fit(gaussFunction, xData, yData, p0)
        newGaussY = gaussFunction(newGaussX, *coeff)
        newGaussY = [x + backGround for x in newGaussY]


        # Generate plot for visual confirmation
        fig = plt.figure()

        ax = fig.add_subplot(111)
        plt.plot(x_data, y_data, 'b*')

        plt.plot((newX[0],newX[-1]),(backGround,backGround),'red')
        plt.plot(newX,newY, color='blue',linestyle='dashed')
        plt.plot(newGaussX, newGaussY, color='green',linestyle='dashed')
        plt.title("Test")
        plt.xlabel("rt [m]")
        plt.ylabel("intensity [au]")
        plt.savefig("Test.pdf",bbox_inches="tight")
        plt.close(fig)
    except:
        pass

# Call the test
#quantify(data)
quantify(data2)
```

where normally the background (red line in below pictures) is dynamically determined, but for the sake of this example I have set it to a fixed number. The problem that I have is that for some data it works really well:

[image]

Corresponding f'(x):

[image]

However, for some other data it fails horrendously:

[image]

Corresponding f'(x):

[image]

Therefore, I would like to hear some suggestions or ideas on why this happens and on potential approaches to fix it. I have included the data that is shown in the picture below (in case anyone wants to try it):

Comment: This belongs on cross validated.

Comment: Have you confirmed that your spline fit in the second example actually works, and that the limits you derive are correct (i.e., your fit data gets limited between 9.67 and 9.98)? That would be a first quick step in debugging this.

Comment: By the way, I'm not sure if I follow your code for determining f' == 0. You seem to be determining the extrema of f', not where it is 0.

Comment: @Evert The blue line is the `InterpolatedUnivariateSpline` so as far as I can tell that is working fine.

Comment: @Evert I wrote f'(x) == 0 indeed. I believe I should have wrote f''(x) == 0, which equates to the local max/min of f'(x), correct me if that's incorrect.

Comment: For a single gaussian, is the value of "mu" always at the point of maximum intensity?  If so, you can use that data point's value of rt in the equation.

Comment: @JamesPhillips I do initialize mu as the point of maximum intensity with the `xData[np.argmax(yData)]` part of p0. However, this is based on the assumption that xData and yData contain only the datapoints between two `f''(x) == 0` values, which I am investigating currently.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

The error lied in the following bit:

```
breaks = maxm[0].tolist() + minm[0].tolist()
for index,j in enumerate(breaks):
```

The `breaks` list now contains both the maxima and minima, but they are not sorted by time. Resulting in the list yielding the following data points for the poor fit: 9.78, 9.62 and 9.86.

The program would then examine data from 9.78 to 9.62 and 9.62 to 9.86, which meant that 9.62 to 9.86 contained the highest intensity data point yielding the fit that is shown in the second graph.

The fix was rather simple by just adding a `sort` on the breaks in between, as follows:

```
breaks = maxm[0].tolist() + minm[0].tolist()
breaks = sorted(breaks)
for index,j in enumerate(breaks):
```

The program then yielded a fit more closely resembling what I would expect:

[image]